# Angular 2 - Cancel pending GET request in HttpInterceptor before POST

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

My API's GET requests are polled at regular intervals. If I make a POST request while the GET request is pending and that POST returns with the new data, the data from the GET request will be outdated.

Using the `HttpInterceptor` can I cancel all pending GET requests before I send the POST?

I've been told that I can just not pass the `req` to the `next.handle()` but what `req` am I supposed to pass then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we talking about Angular 2, you probably call your API in the next way:

```
this.http.get('url').map(res => { ... }).catch(error => { ... });
```

It returns Observable and once you subscribe to it, it returns a subscription. Once you unsubscribe - it will cancel your request. See complete example:

**service.ts**

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('url').map(res => { ... }).catch(error => { ... });
}
```

**component.ts**

```
requestSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
   this.requestSubscription = this.service.getData().subscribe(data => { ... });
}

someFuncWhereYouHandlePOSTSuccess() {
   if (this.requestSubscription) {
      this.requestSubscription.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

Hope this concept is clear enough. If not - I'm ready to answer your questions.

### Edit

Since the OP led me on the right path I figured my solution belongs next to his suggestion as the correct answer.

**Solution service.ts**

```
private breakPolling: boolean = false;

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
}

getData() {
    return this.httpClient
        .get(this.url)
        .map((response) => {
            if (this.breakPolling) {
                this.breakPolling = false;
                return Observable.empty();
            } else {
                return response;
            }
        });
}

breakPolling() {
    this.breakPolling = true;
    return Observable.empty();
}
```

I dispatch an action that will call the `breakPolling()` method and set a simple bool. Instead of returning the response data as an observable I just return an empty Observable.

It doesnt cancel the request, but it prevents its data from being passed on. Its ugly, but it'll patch.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. I'm using ngrx but I think I tie that to a simple action to dispatch. I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Yeah. I have some experience with ngrx and if you dispatch new action on your POST success you can tie this unsubscribe to @Effect of this action type.

Comment: So since you're familiar with ngrx, how can I subscribe to the service request but still return the results of that subscription as an observable in my `@Effect`?

Comment: Hm.. I see what you're saying. You can probably store this subscription in the shared service, but maybe you can do this is in a different way. Choose what best fits your current architecture.